# Get from certain sql range

Tags: mysql, gaps-and-islands

I have the following `video` table:

```
create table videos(
  title text,
  date_range text);
  
insert into videos(title, date_range) values 
('Title1', '["2021-03-18 - 2021-03-20", "2021-03-01 - 2021-03-05", "2021-03-15"]'),
('Title2', '["2021-02-12 - 2021-02-13", "2021-02-02 - 2021-02-06","2021-02-10"]');
```

```
+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| title  |                date_range                                            |
+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Title1 | ["2021-03-18 - 2021-03-20", "2021-03-01 - 2021-03-05", "2021-03-15"] |
| Title2 | ["2021-02-12 - 2021-02-13", "2021-02-02 - 2021-02-06","2021-02-10"]  |
+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

How to get videos from `2021-03-18 - 2021-03-19`?

So the result table should look like this:

```
+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| title  |                date_range                                            |
+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Title1 | ["2021-03-18 - 2021-03-20", "2021-03-01 - 2021-03-05", "2021-03-15"] |
+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Here you have [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wPCEkymzZeBsthv23ZZVBQ/0) with this table, but with no result, because I do not know how to achieve this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider normalising your schema

Answer (score 1):

A normalised schema might be somewhat as follows:

```
id title  date_range_start date_range_end
 1 Title1 2021-03-18       2021-03-20
 2 Title1 2021-03-01       2021-03-05
 3 Title1 2021-03-15       2021-03-15
 4 Title2 2021-02-12       2021-02-13
 5 Title2 2021-02-02       2021-02-06
 6 Title2 2021-02-10       2021-02-10
```

Comment: I do not want to do that, is it any way to do this without normalizing schema?

Comment: Strawberry is right here. If you want to be able to make dated queries, you'll have to normalize the way he did. You could also have a table with the titles linked to a daterange table to achieve the same. Anyway your schema is not suitable for date queries.

Comment: As I see it you have two choices: 1. Normalise your schema. 2. Don't bother with an RDBMS